# UIMutableIndexPath release for UITableView reloadData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, release

I sometimes get a crash with this error `[UIMutableIndexPath release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x205a2930` when I try to execute :

```
[self.detailsTableView reloadData];
```

The cellForRowAtIndexPath method is here :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    DetailResultCell *cell = (DetailResultCell*) [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DETAIL_RESULT_CELL_ID];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:DETAIL_RESULT_CELL_ID owner:self options:nil];
        cell = detailResultCell;
    }
    cell.detailsResultatViagerViewController = self;
    [cell cellWithIndexPath:indexPath andChamp:[[self.resultats objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;
}
```

How can I avoid this ? I try to put a try/catch block around the `[self.detailsTableView reloadData];` but the crash still happens...

Comment: Show where you `init` and 'release' Your `detailsTableView` ?

Comment: on which called that method [self.detailsTableView reloadData];

Comment: What is `cell = detailResultCell`? Where is the `detailResultCell` declared? Also what is done in `cellWithIndexPath:andChamp:objectAtIndex:` method?